# How to mass update sales price for specific opportunities?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Trying to mass update sales price for a bunch of our opportunities. Any guidance on how best to get this done?
Thx

Comment: Have you looked at any resources?

Comment: yes - read quite a bit on different sites and threads within salesforce help portal. It sounds like upsert with data loader is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to salesforce. I think what you are saying might be done by Data Loader . first you export the fields of the object you want to update and do a quick mass update in Excel and then upsert it back. You can narrow the fields you export and the number of entries in the query when you export.